# Java - Keep getting a path error even after using urlencode

Tags: java, android

I'm simply trying to do a HttpGet.

Here is the string that is being passed:

```
fullString = "?nOne=" + node1 + "&nTwo=" + node2 + "&nThree=" + node3 + "&nFour=" + node4 + "&power=" + power + "&color=" + colorRGB;
```

All the variables are a single integer except for color which is 9 digits.

That string is passed to a function doing the following:

```
String get_url = URLEncoder.encode("http://192.168.30.80/" + str, "UTF-8");
HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget;
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
httpget = new HttpGet(get_url);
String content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

I originally just tried:

```
String get_url = "http://192.168.30.80/" + str;
```

But that gave me an illegal character error.  After trying urlencode now I get a:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://192.168.30.80/[Ljava.lang.String;@1a50d830
```

Why can't it just be a string? (Obviously this is my first attempt with android/java)
Please help me understand what is going wrong, thanks.

Comment: Where do you declare `str`? is it a `String` or `String[]`?

Comment: So.. It seems that I learned something today. That String... means list. So when I reference that string str[0] works.  Thanks @BobTheBuilder

Answer (score 0):

`URLEncoder.encode` does not encode a full URL but should be used for the values of the GET parameters.

eg.

```
fullString = "?nOne=" + URLEncoder.encode(node1, "UTF-8");
fullString += "&nTwo=" + URLEncoder.encode(node2, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Tried this.   Got the following error.  Error:(47, 51) error: no suitable method found for encode(int,String)
method URLEncoder.encode(String,String) is not applicable
(actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
method URLEncoder.encode(String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: well, `encode` expects a string and you pass it an integer. `encode` will not modify characters 0..9 so there is no need to encode positive integers. Only encode those parameters that may be problematic in a URL, and make sure you convert them to strings before passing to encode.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response, the path is not getting parsed to extract the scheme or host as these are both null.

Looking at the documentation, it should work from a string.  Have you checked that the string is correctly encoded?  It seems like it is unable to identify the scheme or host.

You could try inspecting the string value before it is passed to the HttpGet, or you might want to try using a URI.

```
URI address = new URI("http://192.168.30.80/" + str);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(address);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```